# maxCombinedSplitSize property in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-configuration

There is a property in pig named

'**pig.maxCombinedSplitSize**' – Specifies the size, in bytes, of data to be processed by a single map. Smaller files are combined until this size is reached.

Is there a similar property in **hive** for specifying the size of data to be processed by a single map?

I am trying the below command but it doesn't work.

```
'SET hive.maxCombinedSplitSize=64mb';
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat;
set mapred.min.split.size=67108864;
```